# Multiple messages same PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, flush

I'm using java and sockets to comunicate a client/server application.

I want to send a message to server like this:

```
is = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

pw.println("MESSAGE");

pw.flush();
```

And that worked well, but then after that I'm trying to send another message

```
pw.println("SECOND MESSAGE");

pw.flush();
```

And the second message is not sending! What can I do?

Comment: try print() method instead of println().

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your server side is consistently reading for more input.  If you only have it say for example performing: 
`bufferedReader.readLine();` 
only once then this is the reason you think it isn't receiving it.  It probably is if the connection isn't closed.

Another possibility since you said it isn't "sending" the second message, is ensure the socket connection remains open and that the reader is still open on the server side and that it wasn't closed after the first message was received.

Answer (score 0):

use `flush()` when all the messages are sent.